# Getting an error while running ADF pipeline through "Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to run ADF pipeline with "Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory" package. .Net code is working fine and also ADF pipeline getting triggered in the Azure portal.

But the ADF pipeline is failing with an error.

Error details:
Operation on target Server failed: ErrorCode=SqlFailedToConnect,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'tcp:SQLServerName', Database: '', User: ''. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Login failed for user ''.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=18456,Class=14,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=14,Number=18456,State=1,Message=Login failed for user ''.,},],'

.Net Code I am using:

```cs
private DataFactoryManagementClient CreateClient(string subscriptionId, string tenantId)
{
    // AzureServiceTokenProvider uses developer credentials when running locally
    // and uses managed identity when deployed to Azure.
    // If getting an exception when running locally, run "az login" command in Azure CLI.
    var provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var token = provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com", tenantId).Result;
    ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(token);

    DataFactoryManagementClient client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials);
    client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    return client;
}

public async Task<string> RunPipelineAsync(string resourceGroupName, string dataFactoryName, string pipelineName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    var runResponse = await client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName, pipelineName, parameters: parameters);
    return runResponse.Body.RunId;
}
```

Comment: What about your data factory configuration ? here you re jsut triggering the pipeline from code but is the pipeline working if you trigger it directly from ADF ? the error is kind of saying the sql connectionstring is not configured properly.

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for the response. Yes, I am able to trigger ADF manually from Azure Portal and it works fine there. Issue I am facing currently is.. when I trigger through .Net code.